# Print won't work in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

When I run this script, it skips the print function in line 8. I cannot figure out why for the life of me. I have tried so many things to get this working but I just can't seem to figure out the problem here. I am very new to Python so excuse me if it's a very simple issue.

Edit: woops, forgot the actual code! *facepalm* here it is:

```
import webbrowser
import sys
b = webbrowser.get('windows-default')
print('Type start')
line1 = sys.stdin.readline()
start = 'start'
if line1 == start:
    print('What website do you want to open?')
line2 = sys.stdin.readline()
b.open(line2)
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the script...

Comment: Haha realized it as soon as I posted. Fixed now!

Comment: Are you aware of [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input)(or [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python 3)? Clearly you're asking for user input here, so better use these methods instead of `sys.stdin.readline`.

Answer (score 5):

When you type `'start'` into stdin and then hit enter, the entire string *including the newline character* ends up being stored in `line1`. So in reality, `line1 == 'start\n'`. You need to remove that `\n` from the end of the string before you do your comparison. An easy way to do that is using [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
if line1.rstrip() == start:
    print('What website do you want to open?')
```

**Edit:**

As Ashwini Chaudhary pointed out in the comments, you should really just be using `raw_input` (or `input` if using Python 3.x) instead of `sys.stdin.readline`. It would make your code shorter, and remove the need to strip the trailing newline altogether:

```
line1 = raw_input('Type start')
start = 'start'
if line1 == start:
    line2 = raw_input('What website do you want to open?')
    b.open(line2)
```